# Bind rows in datatables.net on fnReloadAjax

Tags: jquery, bind, datatables

I am using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) and I am using this code to get clickable rows, called from `fnInitComplete`:

```
function createClickableRowsAllTickets() {
      $(allTable.fnGetNodes()).click( function() {
           alert('row clicked');        
      });
}
```

This works fine. However when I use `fnReloadAjax` to update the table the row clicks are no longer bound.

I tried to call the function once again on the callback of the `fnReloadAjax` but it doesn't work:

```
$("#alltickets input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    allTable.fnReloadAjax('get_tickets', createClickableRowsAllTickets());
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Code should be:

```
$("#alltickets input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
allTable.fnReloadAjax('get_tickets', function() { createClickableRowsAllTickets();},    null);
});
```

instead of:

```
$("#alltickets input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
allTable.fnReloadAjax('get_tickets', createClickableRowsAllTickets());
});
```

note the use of function() in the callback parameter.

Comment: How about just using the function name `createClickableRowsAllTickets` without the parenthesis?